# Right click menu chrome bug, how to fix this?

Tags: updates, chromium, menu

Updated to Impish Indri and I'm seeing this right click menu on chrome. Not always, like in half the pages. This page included.

I'm running in on Ryzen 3 3200g, and I've updated/upgraded to newest version.

[image]